# Company intercepted mail to former employee

Tags: professionalism, email

We maintain the email account of a former employee of our CPA firm to insure that client emails directed to our firm through that email are dealt with.

We received an email at the former employee’s address from an attorney obviously attempting to communicate with the former at her new competing firm referring to members of our firm in a derogatory manner. Are there any restrictions on how we can use or disseminate the intercepted email?

Comment: What locations did this occur in?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you speak to a lawyer in your area who is familiar with the local laws, this could be a real legal nightmare if handled incorrectly.

Comment: What is your position? This should be handled by top management level as there are several avenues it could go. And locale would be important as well.

Comment: Who owns and controls the domain tyhe account is in?

Comment: "insure" is a typo - it is "ensure".  please edit.

Comment: My guess is this is a difficult legal issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm pretty sure this would be a hot legal issue.  Legal questions apparently can't be answered on here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just delete the email and pretend you never saw it. Sure, it was unprofessional to refer to your firm in an inappropriate fashion, but I doubt that following up on it is going to be worth the enormous headache it presents.

Alternatively, you might want to reply to the email saying that the original owner of the email is no longer reachable at that address and not comment on its contents.

Comment: And when the lawyer gets in touch with the ex-employee by other means, to ask why they did not get a reply?

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking about how to correct this lawyer's mistake.  I think he was asking about legal implications of using this information within his own firm.  If this former employee is actually speaking to a lawyer *about their firm* that carries some obvious implications they might want to react to.

Answer (score 0):

If person is no longer with the company, his email address should have been disabled and auto-response set in place to guide senders to a general company channels.

Anything less then that is invasion of privacy, also it can be interpreted as fraud, trading on someone else`s name that is not your right

Comment: Not at all. It's their work email address. There isn't supposed to be any private email coming in. And the company has the right to reply to emails addressed to this person's company email.

Comment: @gnasher729 they don't work  there any more and spying on ex employees email is you know very illegal and also could lead to problems with the certifying body - you can get barred for life

Comment: @Neuromancer - I'm not sure where you're from, but in the US, it is standard practice at many companies to redirect a former employee's email to their manager or successor for about 6 months or so to ensure no critical communication is lost / missed.

Comment: @WesleyLong, I think Neuromancer is in Europe. In Europe, this would be very illegal. In the US, like you said, this would be fine and is actually commonplace.

Comment: @Neuromancer It's not spying. The ex-employee was apparently an idiot who gave their lawyer their former company email address instead of their private email (or even the current company email address). Even in Europe, the company can read your email if they have a good reason. Having to sort out emails coming from customers is a good reason.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk No, it wouldn't be "very illegal". Using the information might be. But then if an attorney is stupid enough to send email to the wrong company (like sending "NiceCompany employees are all idiots" to "former.employee@nicecompany.com"), then I don't think the attorney has any expectation of privacy.

Comment: @gnasher729 the point is he Is an ex employee now

Comment: @Neuromancer The point is that as an ex employee, he shouldn't give his old company email to his attorney. And the email address belongs to his ex-employer. It is a reasonable assumption that employees receive private emails on their company email account, but not for ex-employees.

Comment: @gnasher729, Let's just agree to disagree on that point.